# iphone: scroll in a view

Tags: iphone, view, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I would like to ask a basic iphone question. I have many TextFields in iPhone view, when I tap to input in a TextField, the Keyboard shows up and hide other TextField. I would like to make the parent view scrollable. Would you please show me the example code?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen for the keyboard up and down notification. and move your view just above  height of keyboard.

In the `ViewWillAppear` method:

```
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

In the `ViewWillDisAppear` method:

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil]; 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

And then have methods referred to above to adjust the position of the bar:

```
-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *) note
{
    CGRect r  = bar.frame, t;
    [[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey] getValue: &t];
    r.origin.y -=  t.size.height;
    bar.frame = r;
}




 -(void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *) note
    {
        CGRect r  = bar.frame, t;
        [[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey] getValue: &t];
        r.origin.y +=  t.size.height;
        bar.frame = r;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but in this case the view can not scroll. If I would like to scroll up/down to look at other textfield, I can not do that by this way. Do you have other solutions?

Comment: Try with putting all your views inside UIScrollView (This will be called container view) after that add tis UIScrollView in self.view addSubViews:iMyUIScrollView ... let me know for any difficulty...

Comment: I add all the TextField to a UIScrollView, that ScrollView is a sub view of UIView (MyViewController). But I still can not scroll the view with many TextField in that. I think I am manipulating with UIScrollView, is that right?

Comment: Now, could you now see your view on top of Keyboard ?

Comment: Use the apple sample code for working with scrollview's                               http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008023

Answer (score 2):

This will give you an idea

[How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

Answer (score 1):

If the parentview is UIScrollView then try something like in textfield delegate

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField
{   

    if (theTextField == textFieldName)  { 
        [scroll scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 160, 280, 440) animated:YES];//choose the rect accordingly.
    }
    return YES; 

}
```